# Not able to load template using ng-view in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-1.6

I am trying to build a basic SPA using `angularJS`, the problem is I am not able to load the template using angularJS, the following is my code

**customAngular.js**

```
var app = angular.module("appModule", ["ngRoute"]);

  app.config([function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "pages/main.html"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl: "pages/about.html"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl: "pages/blog.html"
    }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' })
}]);
```

**HTML PAGE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="~/styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/styles/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/angularJS/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/angularJS/customAngular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="appModule">
    <a href="/">main</a>
    <a href="/green">Green</a>
    <a href="/red">red</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me to understand the error

**UPDATE 1**

has bneen modified

**UPDATE 2**

i have updated the page as per the request, i have changed the angular in to unminified version 1.6

```
  <script src="~/angularJS/angular.v1.6.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/angularJS/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="~/angularJS/customAngular.js"></script>
```

and changed my customAngular.js file like this

```
var app = angular.module("appModule", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "pages/main.html"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl: "pages/about.html"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl: "pages/blog.html"
    }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' })
}]);
```

now i am able to see the index page like this
[index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyu4z.png)
but when i move my page to /red, i get an error like this
[error page on redirection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqmma.png)

Comment: Can you add your error?

Comment: @AvneshShakya i could embed the image, but there was a link were you been able to see the image of the error

Comment: I suggest you to use `ui-router`

Comment: Try changing relative url as '#/red' instead of '/red'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have injected your `$routeProvider` the wrong way:

```
app.config([function ($routeProvider) {
    /* $routeProvider will be undefined */
    ...
}]);
```

Thing is, you mixed two ways of Angular injection:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    ...
});
```

And

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    ...
}]);
```

You put `[]` around your function, so Angular expected to see some component identifiers as strings in the head of the array. So, simply remove the square brackets or add the component identifier, as shown in the two examples above.

### Update

You still see an error because, as @Gayathri pointed out in the comments, you are trying to access the URI `/red` on your server... which doesn't exist. You links should be like:

```
<a href="#">main</a>
<a href="#green">Green</a>
<a href="#red">red</a>
```

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrpMag).

Comment: please see my update, i have resolved the error on the home page but my other page gets the error

Comment: This is an entirely new question, I think you better ask it on another thread. Also, please refrain from updating your question after seeing the answers: keep it the way it was, it may help others as well. I suggest you revert back your question to the original issue, and then create another for your new problem.

Comment: why shoudl i change the question when the isssue is not resolved, i just changed the angular version file

Comment: @LijinDurairaj: have this fixed your issue? If so, don't forget to accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>`

Comment: well i have just included the file and styill it is not working

Comment: try the uncompressed version;https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js